# How do I combine two (or more) base models in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a base model that defines behaviour for the URL property.

I also have a separate base model that integrates the Backbone model with Knockout.

```
BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function () {
        // some custom stuff
    }
});

KoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    viewModel: {},
    initialize: function (options) {
        Backbone.Model.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);
        // sets up the view model
        // listens to changes to update the view model when the model changes, etc.
    }
});
```

I now need to create a model that has functionality from both bases.

I've tried `_.mixin`:

```
_.mixin(KoModel, BaseModel);

SomeModel = KoModel.extend({defaults: {foo: 'bar'}});
```

I've tried `extend`:

```
SomeModel = KoModel.extend(BaseModel, {defaults: {foo: 'bar'}});
```

Neither of these attempts, or a few other similar permutations, has worked.

I've also tried using prototype to define the base models as follows:

```
var KoModel = Backbone.Model.extend();

KoModel.prototype.viewModel = {};

KoModel.prototype.initialize = function (options) {
    Backbone.Model.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);
    // etc.
};
```

How do I go about getting a new model to inherit from both of these bases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if I extend using the prototype instead it works:

```
var model = BaseModel.extend(KoModel.prototype);

model.extend({defaults: {foo: 'bar'}});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create "inheritance tree" like that:

```
BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: function () {
            // some custom stuff
        }
    });

KoModel = BaseModel.extend({
    viewModel: {},
    initialize: function (options) {
        Backbone.Model.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);
        // sets up the view model
        // listens to changes to update the view model when the model changes, etc.
    }
});
SomeModel = KoModel.extend({defaults: {foo: 'bar'}});
```

Comment: That approach would mean *all* KoModels have the BaseModel's URL behaviour, which isn't desired.